# How to provide warnings during validation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

Sometimes user input is not strictly invalid but can be considered problematic.

For example:

- A user enters a long sentence in a single-line `Name` field. *He probably should
  have used the `Description` field instead*.
- A user enters a `Name` that is very similar to that of an existing entity. *Perhaps he's inputting the same entity but didn't realize it already exists, or some concurrent user has just entered it.*

Some of these can easily be checked client-side, some require server-side checks.

**What's the best way**, perhaps something similar to `DataAnnotations` validation, **to provide warnings to the user in such cases?** The key here is that the user has to be able to override the warning and still submit the form (or re-submit the form, depending on the implementation).

The most viable solution that comes to mind is to create some attribute, similar to a `CustomValidationAttribute`, that may make an AJAX call and would display some warning text but doesn't affect the `ModelState`. The intended usage is this:

```
[WarningOnFieldLength(MaxLength = 150)]
[WarningOnPossibleDuplicate()]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.WarningMessageFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you want something like `[WarningOnFieldLength(150)]` as an attribute?

Comment: Something like this answer gets you partway there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9652582/534109 - the attribute could be used to generate a hook for the extension, assuming you want to use strongly-type helpers. I'll see if I can scrape something together for a real answer...

Comment: @TiesonT. the answer you link to suggest I should use it if I don't have multiple validations on a field, which I do. Anyway, I'm not sure how to generate a hook for the extension, so an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Overall Design**

To start with, I believe you would have to track somehow if the user choose to ignore the warnings. A simple and transparent way to do that is to have an *Ignore Warnings* check-box, which user would have to check before submit. Another option is a have them submit the form two times and ignore the warnings on the second submit; then you'd probably need an *IgnoreWarnings* hidden field. There could be other designs, but for the sake of simplicity I'll go with the first option.

In short, the approach is to create

- A custom data annotation attribute for all view models supporting the warning type of validation;
- A known base class which the view models will inherit from;
- We'll have to duplicate the logic in JavaScript for each custom attribute.

Please note that the code below just illustrates the approach and I have to assume quite a lot of things without knowing the full context.

**View Model**

In this scenario it's best to separate a view model from an actual model which is a good idea anyway. One possible approach is to have a base class for all view models which support warnings:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public bool IgnoreWarnings { get; set; }
}
```

The key reason a model needs to be separate is that there's little sense in storing the `IgnoreWarnings` property in your database.

Your derived view model will then look as follows:

```
public class YourViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLengthWarning(MaximumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Your Warning Message")]
    public string YourProperty { get; set; }
}
```

`StringLengthWarning` is a custom data annotation attribute for server and client-side validation. It just supports the maximum length and can easily be extended with any other necessary properties.

**Data Annotation Attribute**

The core of the attribute is `IsValid(value, validationContext` method.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class StringLengthWarningAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    public int MaximumLength { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as BaseViewModel;
        var str = value as string;
        if (!model.IgnoreWarnings && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || str.Length > MaximumLength))
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new StringLengthWarningValidationRule(MaximumLength, ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

The attribute implements `IClientValidatable` and utilizes a custom client validation rule:

```
public class StringLengthWarningValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public StringLengthWarningValidationRule(int maximumLength, string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "stringlengthwarning";
        ValidationParameters.Add("maximumlength", maximumLength);
        ValidationParameters.Add("ignorewarningsfield", "IgnoreWarnings");
    }
}
```

**Client-side JavaScript**

Finally, to make it work, you'll need the following JavaScript referenced from your view:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('stringlengthwarning', function (value, element, params) {
        var maximumlength = params['maximumlength'];
        var ignorewarningsfield = params['ignorewarningsfield'];

        var ctl = $("#" + ignorewarningsfield);
        if (ctl == null || ctl.is(':checked'))
            return true;
        return value.length <= maximumlength;
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("stringlengthwarning", ["maximumlength", "ignorewarningsfield"], function (options) {
        var value = {
            maximumlength: options.params.maximumlength,
            ignorewarningsfield: options.params.ignorewarningsfield
        };
        options.rules["stringlengthwarning"] = value;
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages["stringlengthwarning"] = options.message;
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

The JavaScript makes some assumptions you might want to revisit (the check-box name, etc).

**UPDATE: HTML Helpers**

To display the validation messages separately for errors and warnings, a couple of helpers will be necessary. The following class provides a sample:

```
public static class  MessageHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString WarningMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState["IgnoreWarnings"] != null)
            return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString ErrorMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState["IgnoreWarnings"] == null)
            return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

In the view they can be used as usual:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourProperty)
        @Html.ErrorMessageFor(model => model.YourProperty)
        @Html.WarningMessageFor(model => model.YourProperty)
```

Comment: Really great, very complete answer. You deserve this bounty!

Comment: Great example of why not to use data annotations. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `depends` function of jquery validation to simplify your life.

Ex.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

<label>Ignore Warnings</label>
<input id="ignore-warnings" type="checkbox" />

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#UserName").rules("add", {
      minlength: {
        param: 6,
        depends: function (element) {
          return !$("#ignore-warnings").attr('checked');
        }
      },

      // server side remote validation for duplicate check
      remote: {
        param: '/account/duplicate',
        depends: function (element) {
          return !$("#ignore-warnings").attr('checked');
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick comment on the possible re-submit implementation you mentioned...

For the "did you mean to do this?" validation type, from a user's perspective, having to re-submit a form based off an assumption that they made a mistake could be very annoying.  I would only implement this 'pseudo-validation' on the client side with javascript and (hopefully quick) ajax calls if you have to hit the server.

I would also attempt to display the warnings on the input's blur/change events so they show before the user hits submit.  Maybe not practical in all situations, but I just thought i'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sketch of a possible solution. There are plenty of examples of adding custom attributes (including above) so I'll skip that bit.

It may be possible to add the use of ignore in the [jQuery validator function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Then use

```
$("form").validate({  
ignore: ".warning-only"
});
```

and use the client side validator to add the 'warning-only' class after a first pass through the validator. This should then allow the form to be sent to the server.

As I say, just a sketch, but it is something I have been researching for furture use.

Comment: @Alex I see that the same solution has been suggested above. Combining this with the answer from Serge Belov below should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do a warning without writing any server-side code.  Add the class "ignore-validation" to the desired invalid elements on form submit, and in your custom validation method return "true" if the element has this class (if it has the class it means the form was submitted once).  You'll also need to remove the "ignore-validation" class from #IdOfInput on blur or change, depending upon the kind of control it is, that bit of code is not represented here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$.validator.addMethod('isValidCustomMethod', function (value, element) {
        if($(element).hasClass('ignore-validation')){
            return true;
        }
        var isValid = false;    //your code to do validation would actually go here
        return isValid;
    });

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#IdOfInput').rules('add', { isValidCustomMethod: true, messages: { isValidCustomMethod: 'Your warning message here'} });

    $('form').submit(function () {
                    $(this).validate().invalidElements().each(function () {
                        if($(this).attr('id')=='IdOfInput'){
                            $(this).addClass('ignore-validation');
                        }
                    });
                });
        }); 
    </script>
```