# Return a warning (not an error) via Ajax remote validation

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC Ajax callback that checks to see if a user input is valid.  This callback is invoked via the [Remote] attribute on the associated model property.

I've changed my design, and I've decided that I would really like to warn the user if the value is incorrect, but I don't want the incorrect value to prevent model validation.

A quick search turns up several threads describing very involved solutions to the general problem of wiring up "unobtrusive warnings" similar to the "unobtrusive validation" magic baked into MVC (for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13319648/1637105)).  I'm not looking for a general solution, and I don't want to spend a lot of time and energy on this, but I'm wondering if some Ajax guru knows of something I can return from the Ajax server routine that would have the effect of causing the unobtrusive validation client-side code to put up the message without triggering the validation error.

FYI, my existing server-side code looks like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> CouponCodeExists(string couponCode, int? planId)
    {
        if (some_logic) {
            return Json("Coupon code is already taken", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } else {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make you own ajax call in the inputs `.change()` event, and in the success callback, display the message (remove the `RemoteAttribute` if you do not want it to trigger a validation error)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Absent any better answers, I'd like to accept your comment as the preferred answer.  If you would be so kind as to post it as an "answer", I'll accept it and be done with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RemoteAttribute` is a validation attribute and triggering it will add a validation error to `jQuery.validate.js` and prevent the form from submitting. If you just want a warning message, and still allow the form to submit, you can just make your own ajax call in the inputs `.change()` event.

Assuming you have `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.couponCode)` in the view, add a placeholder for the message - say `<div id="couponwarning">Coupon code is already taken</div>` and style in as `display: none;`. Then add the following scripts

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CouponCodeExists")';
var warning = $('#couponwarning');
$('#couponCode').change(function() {
    var code = $(this).val();
    var id = .... // the value of your planId input?
    $.get(url, { couponCode: code, planId: id }, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            warning.show();
        }
    });
});
$('#couponCode').keyup(function() {
    warning.hide();
});
```

and the method can just return `true` to display the message, or `null`

```
if (some_logic) {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} else {
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```