# How to warn the user during form input in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The user sometimes should be warned about an input but the input is not technically invalid.

I want to implement something like this:

```
[Range(5, 2147483647, "It's best if you enter a lower number")]
public int duration { get; set;}
```

PS - I have seen this [How to provide warnings during validation in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319648/how-to-provide-warnings-during-validation-in-asp-net-mvc)
but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code (view, models, etc)?

Comment: You need to try the solution suggested in the other question. And also try to read about whatever is used in that. That will help you to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it during form input- without posting the form back, you should use Javascript for the task, not C#. 
Your Range attribute only works in backend code.

You can use some ready to use javascript libraries. For example [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)